# Evolution of Earth - Yoga Vashishtha

Tags: history, rama, vashishta, yoga-vashishtha

Yoga Vashishtha, is a conversation between *Maharishi Vashistha* and Shri Rama. *Shri Rama*, when young, comes to the palace back after travelling the country and is very despondent. Rishi Vashishtha gives him knowledge and the conversation happens on various topics.

The *Yoga Vashishtha* covers the mysterious topics of time, space, consciousness etc.

Although, the question is: Are there any records on the evolution of Earth mentioned in the text?

Answer (score 3):

In Yoga Vashishtha, the conversation between Sage Vashishtha and Bhusunda mentions how Earth evolved over time.

> Sage Vasishstha asked:
>
> You enjoy such longevity as would suggest that you have attained final
>   liberation! And, you are wise, brave and a great yogi. **Pray, tell me
>   what extra-ordinary events you remember, relating to this and the
>   previous world-cycles.**

Bhusunda narrates such events in great details. I am mentioning only a part of the answer here.

> Bhusunda said:
>
> …I remember that once upon a time there was nothing on this Earth,
>   neither trees and plants, nor even mountains. For a period of eleven
>   thousand years the Earth was under lava…
>
> …[Later] apart from the polar region, the rest of the Earth was
>   covered by water. And then forests enveloped the Earth, and great
>   asuras (demons) ruled.
>
> Then there arose great mountains, but without any human inhabitants.
>   For a period of ten thousand years, the
>   Earth was covered with the corpses of the asuras (daityas)…”

Bhusunda continues like this for quite a time, narrating more events. For more, read here:  [www.estudantedavedanta.net/The-Supreme-Yoga-Swami-Venkatesananda.pdf](http://www.estudantedavedanta.net/The-Supreme-Yoga-Swami-Venkatesananda.pdf)

Shloka number: 6.1.21.

Comment: Could asuras here be dinosaurs?

Comment: @Amit Saxena I think this is a false verse.